# What is making this horizontal scroll bar pop up?

Tags: css, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling, fluid-layout, fluid

I've got a one page site that I'm building for myself and I've got a small but annoying (to me) bug.

I'm working on making it media query friendly, and so far what I'm learning is coming together ok. What's bugging me is that when the site is being resized horizontally, there's a part where the horizontal scroll bar flashes up.

You can see where in the screenshot. It's around the width of 767px.

[image: scrollbar screenshot]

I think it might be coming from the 1140.css file, the framework I'm using to make it responsive, but I can't figure out what's causing it or how to fix it.

You can check my site out:

http://vitaliyg.com

Comment: Is it browser specific? I didn't get the scroll bar in Chrome

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me. I'm in Chrome in OSX. Might have to scroll slow. It's a replicable issue for me

Comment: Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera on OSX 10.8; none of them show the scroll bar.

Comment: Scroll slow. I've replicated the issue in Chrome and Safari in OSX 10.8. It only shows up in a span of a pixel or two at 767px browser width.

Comment: Ok, could replicate it when I resized the window really carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From giving it a blast in Chrome it looks like it is due to

```
media="screen" 1140.css:10
.container {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

If these are both turned off the scroll bar doesn't appear.. for me at least.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works for me as well. I figured it had to do something with excess padding or margins.
Thanks for looking into this for me. Hopefully commenting these out won't be too dangerous :P

Comment: Although it's probably not ideal you could add another class to the container (or maybe even just body > .container) and then remove the padding-left/right on that. That way you may not bother anything else.

Comment: Since there is nothing else associated to .container, wouldn't that be just moving padding to another class?

Comment: Yeah it would be adding the padding to an extra class but then you could use .container elsewhere and have it style the way it is supposed to rather that how you have bodged it.